# white space on top of recycler view android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have a problem with one of my screens, it has a recycler view and it loads images as you scroll down, I have not idea what it could be, I have tried tons of things around the internet but none of that have worked for me. Here is a image:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IsTC2.png)

Still, It does not happen all the time, only in certain phones and in certain moments, so I can't see the images properly, this is my code:

**Activity_timeline.xml**

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/myScrollingContent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/item_progress_bar"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"/>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <!--<ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/item_progress_bar"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
        android:visibility="gone" /> -->

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

    <com.roughike.bottombar.BottomBar
        android:id="@+id/bottomBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:bb_tabXmlResource="@xml/bottombar_tl"
        app:bb_behavior="shy"
        app:bb_activeTabColor="@color/bb_darkBackgroundColor"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</layout>
```

**timeline_stucture.xml**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="5dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview_name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<com.github.chrisbanes.photoview.PhotoView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textview_name"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview_birth_death"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:textSize="18dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 0):

solved! My problems was that in Activity_timeline.xml the CoordinatorLayout was match_parent instead of fill_parent, that work for me. In case you were curious